# Firebase get call works on android, but has a strange behaviour on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter

I have a flutter application that is already used by my client for almost 2 months on android and now I have to make the iOS version as well.

When I try to run a get call with the userAccount.id, I get the data returned from firebase 6 times but then I get a "Transaction failed all retries" error.

I tried everything that I was able to find on google.

NOTE: streaming data from firebase works correctly

I am using the cloud_firestore flutter package

Here is the function:

```
  static Future<WebRequestResponse> getUserAccountByID(String id) async {
    if (!await isInternetConnectionAvailable()) {
      return WebRequestResponse(false, null, null,
          errorType: ErrorType.ERROR_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
    }
    DocumentSnapshot ds;
    final TransactionHandler getTransaction = (Transaction tx) async {
      ds = await tx.get(userAccountsCollection.document(id));
      print(ds.data);
      return ds.data;
    };

    WebRequestResponse response = WebRequestResponse(false, null, null);
    return Firestore.instance.runTransaction(getTransaction).then((jsonData) {
      print(jsonData);
      UserAccount userAccount = UserAccount.fromJson(jsonData);
      print(userAccount.id);
      if (userAccount.id != null) {
        response.success = true;
        response.data = userAccount;
        return response;
      } else {
        response.success = false;
        response.errorType = ErrorType.ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND;
        return response;
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('get_user_account_by_id_error: $error');
      response.success = false;
      response.error = error;
      response.errorType = ErrorType.ERROR_UNKNOWN;
      return response;
    });
  }
```

This is the response I get:

```
flutter: {id: Edaavf39l4Y3cbfGy4RblYSdy1p1, profilePictureURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fr<REDACTED REST OF JSON>}
flutter: {id: Edaavf39l4Y3cbfGy4RblYSdy1p1, profilePictureURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fr<REDACTED REST OF JSON>}
flutter: {id: Edaavf39l4Y3cbfGy4RblYSdy1p1, profilePictureURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fr<REDACTED REST OF JSON>}
flutter: {id: Edaavf39l4Y3cbfGy4RblYSdy1p1, profilePictureURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fr<REDACTED REST OF JSON>}
flutter: {id: Edaavf39l4Y3cbfGy4RblYSdy1p1, profilePictureURL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fr<REDACTED REST OF JSON>}
flutter: get_user_account_by_id_error: PlatformException(9, Transaction failed all retries., null)
```

As you can see the data is printed out correctly by the print inside the transaction, but it happens 6 times and it fails after. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please ensure, you have don't miss any steps https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-integrate-your-ios-flutter-app-with-firebase-on-macos-6ad08e2714f0

Comment: I checked it multiple times. If you are using the cloud firestore package, You only have to copy the GoogleService-Info.plist into your runner folder I believe.


"**Don't follow the steps named "Add Firebase SDK" and "Add initialization code" in the Firebase assistant.**" - cloud firestore package.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few weeks of struggle and trying out random things, I figured that it may be because I was running flutter in a virtual machine (wasn't able to confirm yet).

Anyway the solution for me was that after every tx.get call I had to add an tx.set call with the same document id and update with empty data. I have no idea why, or how this works but it does. I though I answer in case anyone runs into the same problem in the future.